# How to programmatically determine the Parts of Speech tag of a word?

Tags: nlp, nltk, grammar, pos-tagger

Been wondering how to determine the POS tag of a word accurately. I played with POS taggers such as Stanford NLP etc, but they hit and miss as a word like "respond" is sometimes tagged as a NN (noun) when it is a verb (VB).

Would querying wordnet, or a dictionary dump be more accurate? Eg the word "respond" is a verb, and can also be a noun. Or perhaps infer from ngrams or add in a frequency based sanity check?

Comment: PoS taggers are trained on manually tagged texts, so they already should have a notion of which tags come with a word, and how often they do so, and – importantly – which tag(s) preceded it. The accuracy depends on the algorithm, the size of the training material, and on the similarity of training and test corpus (eg. in terms of genre and domain). PoS tagging is not perfect, but if you get really bad quality then there might be a misconfiguration (like differences in tokenisation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A POS Tagger is traditionally based on a probability distribution of words over a corpus. Therefore extending use-case to a new body of text will usually yield higher error rates, since the distribution of words is different.

Other models are not strictly a Probability Distribution, such as Neural Networks, and need to be trained but the same logic holds true for both.

For example, if I make a POS tagger for `Shakespeare` texts by using tagged sentences from `Hamlet` to define my probability distribution, then try to POS tag `Biomedical` texts, it probably won't perform well.

Therefore, to increase accuracy, *you should train with a body of text that is similar to your specific domain.*

The current best performing POS tagger in NLTK is the Perceptron Tagger which is the default and uses a pre-trained model. Here is how you would train your own model to increase accuracy.

```
import nltk,math
# get data to train and test
tagged_sentences = [sentence for sentence in nltk.corpus.brown.tagged_sents(categories='news',tagset='universal')]
# hold out 20% for testing, get index for 20% split
split_idx = math.floor(len(tagged_sentences)*0.2)
# testing sentences are words only, list(list(word))
testing_sentences = [[word for word,_ in test_sent] for test_sent in tagged_sentences[0:split_idx]]
# training sentences words and tags, list(list(word,tag))
training_sentences = tagged_sentences[split_idx:] 
# create instance of perceptron POS tagger
perceptron_tagger = nltk.tag.perceptron.PerceptronTagger(load=False)
perceptron_tagger.train(training_sentences)
pos_tagged_sentences = [perceptron_tagger.tag([word for word,_ in test_sentence]) for test_sentence in testing_sentences]
```

after `perceptron_tagger.train()` finishes on the `training_sentences`, you can use `perceptron_tagger.tag()` to get `pos_tagged_sentences` which are more useful to your domain and produce a much higher accuracy.

If done right, they will produce high-accuracy results. From [my basic tests](https://natemccoy.github.io/2016/10/27/evaluatingnltktaggerstutorial.html), they show the following results:

```
Metrics for <nltk.tag.perceptron.PerceptronTagger object at 0x7f34904d1748>
 Accuracy : 0.965636914654
 Precision: 0.965271747376
 Recall   : 0.965636914654
 F1-Score : 0.965368188021
```

Comment: Thx! I don't insist on using POS tagging. Would a Google based ngram approach work better? Perhaps check if verb or noun is more frequent for this and that word pair or word triplet.

Comment: @giorgio79 You can use a reduced set of POS labels, like only noun–verb–other, but it's still POS tagging. Google n-grams (if that's what you mean) won't help, since they don't have POS tags AFAIK.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/info  (they call it parts-of-speech tagging) and here http://storage.googleapis.com/books/ngrams/books/datasetsv2.html :)
What I meant by my comment is that I don't insist on a statistical pos tagging approach. Brute force may be the most accurate (eg a dictionary style lookup in ngram frequencies)

Comment: @giorgio79 The most accurate brute force approach would be manually tagging a corpus for POS. Machine learning implementations are the state of the art approach

Comment: @giorgio79 Thanks, I didn't know they provided POS tags as well. I still think this won't help you, as those tags were predicted automatically – the authors estimate the accuracy to be around 95%, so it's probably similar to the kind you experienced already.

Comment: @Nathan, your code snippet looks like you are training and testing on the same data. I'm sure you didn't make that mistake, but maybe expand the code to make that clear?

Comment: @alexis good point. updated answer to be more explicit in split of training and testing data.

Comment: Also been wondering how NLTP perceptron and Stanford POS Tagger stack up against each other.

Answer (score 2):

POS tagging is a surprisingly hard problem, considering how easy it seems when a human does it. POS taggers have been written using many different approaches, and the Stanford tagger is among the best general-purpose taggers for English. (See [here](https://www.aclweb.org/aclwiki/index.php?title=POS_Tagging_(State_of_the_art)) for a pretty authoritative comparison.) So if the approaches you suggest are any good--and some of them are--, they are in use already.

If you think you can build a better tagger, by all means give it a go; it will be a great learning experience. But don't be surprised if you can't beat a state of the art POS tagger at what it does.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried [TextBlob](https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/)? One friend of mine was taking a linguistics course and they all use that to mark POS. 
This is a Python library. You may install by package manager `pip`.

```
$ pip install -U textblob
```

When using,

```
>> from textblob import TextBlob
```

There is a more detailed [tutorial](http://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/quickstart.html). 
You may also install their corpora NLTK. (I can't post link, but just search, tutorials exists in abundance)

Comment: Apparently, the OP knows how to use a PoS tagger, but is concerned with the accuracy. Given the one-button-approach of textblob with little to no control of what is actually happening, this is not of any help, I think.